# dnu publish - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx, project.json, dnu

When running the following `dnu publish`, I get an ArgumentNullException exception thrown.

```
dnu publish "C:\Project\MyProject" --out "C:\a" --configuration Debug --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6
```

Exception thrown:

```
Restoring packages for C:\a\approot\src\RelatedProject\project.json
----------
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Project.GetTargetFramework(FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ProjectReferenceDependencyProvider.GetDescription(LibraryRange libraryRange, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.LocalWalkProvider.FindLibrary(LibraryRange libraryRange, FrameworkName targetFramework, Boolean includeUnlisted)
   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations.<FindProjectMatch>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryMatch>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations.<FindLibraryEntry>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations.<CreateGraphNode>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreCommand.<CreateGraphNode>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreCommand.<RestoreForProject>d__70.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass69_0.<<Execute>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreCommand.<Execute>d__69.MoveNext()
----------
Restore failed
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
```

The `project.json` for RelatedProject is as follows:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "MyProject.Domain.Model Class Library",

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure dnu publish is working with xproj file as one of its arguments. Try source directory path (the directory where you have project.json).

Comment: @tugberk: Apologies, that was a typo.  I am using the `project.json` path as you suggested. Post fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came down to the fact that MyProject was targeting `dnx451` and RelatedProject (referenced by MyProject) was targeting `net451`.  Changing RelatedProject to target `dnx451` fixed the problem on `dnu publish`.